# How to display JSON keys in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have some JSON which looks like this:

```
    {
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "someName",
            "link": "http://somelink.com",
            ],
            "relevantArray": [
                {
                    "keyIWant": 42
                }
            ],
            ...
     }
```

and I get the data like this:

```
<li v-for="(dataVue, index) in dataList.feat" :key="index">
          {{ dataVue.someName }}
          {{ dataVue.link}}
          {{ dataVue.??? }}
</li>
```

what do I write to return keyIWant - the name of the **key**, not the value (42)??

**EDIT:** 
I can output the JSON by writing

```
{{dataVue.relevantArray}}
```

But this returns the JSON like this:

```
[ { "relevantArray": keyIwant } ]
```

and I just can't get the relevantArray to return by itself.
CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-wu-41kyz?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: `Object.keys(dataVue.relevantArray[0])[0]`?

Comment: [Have you considered searching for the answer before posting?](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object) Have you checked what your `index` variable holds?

Comment: Uh, how do I input that in Vue.js?
{{ Object.keys(featData.prerequisite[0])[0] }} is invalid
assuming you mean keys = key, but this breaks Vue.js

Comment: maybe this? `{{dataVue.releventArray[0].keyIwant}}`

Comment: That returns the value - ie. 42, not the key/name of it.

Comment: @monkapish
the index is empty, which confuses me as well

Comment: @Nivyan [It should work](https://jsfiddle.net/6aoLe4gu/)

Comment: @monkapish
index, dataVue.index, and dataVue.relevantArray.index

...Because I import the JSON:
import JSONdoc from "path";
...
data(){
 return {
data: JSONdoc
}
}

Comment: `Object.keys(dataVue.relevantArray[0])` this worked for me based on your example

Comment: @Nurfey I'm writing that to replace {{dataVue.???}} - but I get an error. Where do you write it?

Comment: @Nivyan could you maybe add a CodePen or something like that, so people can help you easier

Comment: @Nurfey Here you go.

Comment: I see the question has already been answered the right way, if you only wanted the first item, see this: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-elbakyan-56d65?file=/src/someData.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-brook-42m3x

Basically you can iterate any object as key-value using v-for

```
<li v-for="(vueData, index) in vueData.data" :key="index">
  {{ vueData.someName }}
  {{ vueData.link }}
   <span
     v-for="(r,ri) in vueData.relevantArray[0]"
     :key="ri"
     >{{ ri }} ==> {{ r }}
   </span>
</li>
```

will give you something like this

```
someName http://somelink.com keyIWant ==> 42
```

Comment: That's almost perfect(!!!!), but in case I got multiple in relevantArray, do I need to wrap it around an additonal v-for?

Answer (score 0):

Arief' answer didn't solve the problem for some reason, but I played around with it and found the following solution:

```
<span
     v-for="(r,ri) in vueData.relevantArray[0]" :key="ri">
      {{ ri }} ==> {{ r }}
         <span v-for="(arrayData, index) in r" :key="index">
            {{index}}
         </span>
   </span>
```

This makes the output I wanted, doing the above solutions outputted the array in my case. I'll mark Arief' solution as the answer, as it lead me to my solution.

If anyone want to tell me why I had to do my version, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks everyone!!